# Set the default value for date_field in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few forms in my application which where using `date_select` and I've just changed to using `date_field` (which uses the HTML5 form elements) the only issue I'm having is that `date_select` would default to todays date which was perfect for us but `date_field` is defaulting to `dd/mm/yyyy` instead.

I'm running into issues with people blindly submitting the form and triggering validation errors.

Is it possible to default `date_field` to today?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you installed Rails4 via gem, it has below bug yet.

https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/datetime_field.rb

Fix above and you can set default value like this

```
<%= f.date_field :birthday, :value => Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>
```

Answer (score 6):

Setting the :value, as many of these answers suggest, will overwrite a value that is passed in for any record being edited. This is not a problem if the form is only for new entries, but buggy if you want to edit records in the form. One way around this is to grab the existing object explicitly, as Michael suggests.

The solution I'm currently using is in the Controller, which sets the value to today when it builds the new record. Assuming your model is Person, and the value you want to default is start_date:

```
def new
    @person = Person.new(start_date: Date.current)
end
```

You can then just use the value in the form without any additional fuss.

```
f.date_field :start_date
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default date_field like this

```
date_field("user", "born_on", value: Time.now.to_s(:db))
```

Comment: Can you please post the date_field line here.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. No matter how you format the :value it never actually shows that date in the field, nor is it in the DOM

Comment: Date.today worked for me.
date_field("user", "born_on", value: Date.today.to_s(:db))

Answer (score 2):

This will run correctly :

```
<%= f.date_field :birthday, :value => Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  %>
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these options worked for me, trying to use a `date_field_tag`.

What did work is passing the value like this:

`date_field_tag(:my_thing_end_date, :end_date, value: Date.current.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

From the docs ( http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/date_field)

> The default value is generated by trying to call “to_date” on the object’s value, which makes it behave as expected for instances of DateTime and ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.

So passing the date as a string that would be entered by the user seems to be the solution.

Also, according to this good info on dates and time zones, `Date.current` is preferable to `Time.today`: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones.

Answer (score 1):

```
f.date_field :birthday, :default=>Date.today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Time object for a date field didn't work for me, I had to use the Date object.

1. I used a placeholder for browsers like Safari to guide them to the proper formatting if it is rendering as a text field.
2. Also if the value already exist (such as when you are in the #edit action) it needs to use that value instead

Resulting view code for Rails 4:

```
<%= f.date_field :birthday, placeholder: "YYYY-MM-DD", value: (f.object.birthday || Date.today.to_s(:db)) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails for you can also do following:
' <%= f.date_field :birthday, :value => Date.today %>

Comment: In Rails 7 this works.